# On authentication triggers I am getting displayName as null

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want to use users data on authentication trigger. But when I am using them it gives me null. What is wrong with my code?

```
exports.sendWelcomeMessage = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    const name = user.displayName;
    console.log(name);
    return null;
})
```

Comment: Are you sure you have set a `displayName`? How do you create a user? Can you share the code?

Answer (score 1):

I speculate you are creating the user and then setting the display name (eg via 2 calls).

`onCreate` triggers as soon as the user is created, eg `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.

When you call `updateProfile` to set the `displayName`, the onCreate event would have already been triggered.

Comment: but then what should I do to get displayName at that time @bojeil

Comment: There is no good way to do it. A hacky way is to add a delay in your trigger and then query the user via the Firebase admin sdk using `admin.auth().getUser(uid)`.